# Unsure of how to manage email configurations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am attempting to create Reset Password functionality using Djoser. I am successfully hitting my API's `auth/users/reset_password/` endpoint, which is then sending an email as expected. But the problem is occurring in the content of the email. It is sending a redirection link to my api, rather than to my frontend.

*Please note, any <> is simply hiding a variable and is not actually displayed like that*

Here is an example of what the email looks like:

```
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at <api>.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password: <api>/reset-password/confirm/<uid>/<token>

Your username, in case you've forgotten: <username>

Thanks for using our site!

The <api> team
```

The goal with this email is to send the user to the `/reset-password/confirm/` url on my frontend, not on my api, which is currently occurring.

Here are my DJOSER settings:

```
DJOSER = {
'DOMAIN': '<frontend>',
'SITE_NAME': '<site-name>',
'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'reset-password/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
}
```

The expected behavior is for the `DOMAIN` setting to alter the link that is being placed in the email, but it is not. I can't seem to find reference to this particular problem within the docs.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

Due to `Djoser` extending the package `django-templated-mail`, the variables `DOMAIN` and `SITE_NAME` have to override `django-templated-mail` setting rather than `Djoser`'s setting. So, you have to pull variables specific to `django-templated-mail` out of the `Djoser` variable.

The working setup actually looks like:

```
DOMAIN = '<frontend>',
SITE_NAME = '<site-name>',
DJOSER = {
'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'reset-password/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
}
```